# JQM Click event doesn't work in Android Webview

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, android-webview

I have an anchor which has three elements. Each element will has to respond for a click event.
I have this as and Android web view app.

Surprisingly click event works in android browser, but when I try that android webview app, nothing happens. Please refer the code below.

I don't know what I am missing so the click events doesn't work in android webview app.

```
$("#cont2 li a").live('click', function (e) {
                //e.preventDefault();
                this.blur();

                var name = $(this).attr("name");
                var staffid = $(this).attr("staffid");
                var recordid = $(this).attr("recordid");
                var primary = $(this).attr("primary");

                if (name == "deletestaff") {
                    // delete sales staff
                    var dretVal = confirm("Delete contact staff " + $(this).attr("staffname") + "?");
                    if (dretVal == false) {
                        return false;
                    } else {

                        var txtprimaryrecordid = $("#txtprimaryrecordid").val();
                        var txtprimarystaffid = $("#txtprimarystaffid").val();

                        if (txtprimaryrecordid == 'undefined') {
                            txtprimaryrecordid = "";
                        }

                        if (txtprimarystaffid == 'undefined') {
                            txtprimarystaffid = "";
                        }

                        if (txtprimaryrecordid == recordid) {
                            $("#txtprimaryrecordid").val("");
                        }
                        if (txtprimarystaffid == staffid) {
                            $("#txtprimarystaffid").val("");
                        }

                        $(this).parents('li').remove();

                        // show deleted item
                        $('#staffs input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                            var delstaffid = $(this).attr("staffid");

                            if (staffid == delstaffid) {
                                $(this).attr("checked", false).checkboxradio("refresh");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Just had to implement WebChromeClient...

```
private class WebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient{
        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message,JsResult result) 
        {
            Log.e("alert triggered", message);
            return false;         
        }
    }
```